# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, youtube

I have an exception and I couldn't find a solution for my problem. I think my whole code is valid c#.

```
namespace YoutubeDownloader2Form
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DownloadUrl DownloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();


            List<Class1> FinalLiast = DownloadUrl.DownloadUrlMethod(textBox1.Text);
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var Urls in FinalLiast)
            {
                string Authorization = Urls.Author;

                IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(Urls.Url);

                VideoInfo Video = videoInfos.First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 144);

                if (Video.RequiresDecryption)
                {
                    DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(Video);
                }

                string path = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Youtube\" + Authorization).ToString();
                var videoDownloader = new VideoDownloader(Video,
                    Path.Combine((@"C:\youtube\" + path), Video.Title + Video.VideoExtension));


                StreamWriter dosya = File.AppendText((@"C:\youtube\" + path) + i + ".txt");

                videoDownloader.Execute();
                //Thread.Sleep(60000);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class DownloadUrl
{
    public List<Class1> DownloadUrlMethod(string txtboxDeger)
    {

        VideoSearch Items = new VideoSearch();
        List<Class1> ListClass1 = new List<Class1>();

        string searchCount =
            txtboxDeger + "&sp=EgIYAVAU";
        foreach (var Item in Items.SearchQuery(searchCount, 1))
        {
            Class1 Video = new Class1();
            Video.title = Item.Title;
            Video.Author = Item.Author;
            Video.Url = Item.Url;
            IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(Video.Url);
            ListClass1.Add(Video);

        }
        return ListClass1;
    }
}
```

The code works fine for three queries, but I have 20. At 3. step, it throws an exception; here's the stack trace:

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>          at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at YoutubeDownloader2Form.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Ramazan BIYIK\source\repos\YoutubeDownloader2Form\YoutubeDownloader2Form\Program.cs:line 26>>

[image: This is the error zone]

You can see from picture where the code throws. I tried asynchronously, and it also throws. I checked the `InnerException`; it says that the given path's format is not supported. But, it downloaded first three videos successfully. It should work fine for other videos too.

Why is this code throwing an exception?

I followed these tutorials to write this code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kv63n_rfJwk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnG3urCD_m0

Comment: Perhaps if you posted the link to the video you're following we might have some context as to what's going on (though code is always better - thank you for posting it!)

Comment: I edited the answer. You can see my sources.